# HDCP content protection using UWP Miracast API

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, miracast, hdcp

I am developing a Miracast sink app following the [UWP Miracast API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.miracast?view=winrt-22621) that must support content protection using HDCP.

Currently, projection of unprotected content works fine. However, the API does not seem to enable HDCP for the Miracast Session and I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation a way to do this.

As stated in the output report of `dxdiag` my hardware supports Miracast with HDCP:

```
Miracast: Available, with HDCP
```

Additionally, sniffing the RTSP packets using Wireshark, the HDCP related parameter in the M3 response is `wfd_content_protection: none` when it would be `wfd_content_protection: HDCP2.1` if HDCP was enabled.

How do I enable it for the Miracast session? Is this a limitation of the UWP API? Or should content protection be enabled through a different API?

Any help is welcome

Comment: Can using PlayReady meet your needs? Here is an official document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/playready-client-sdk#miracast

Comment: Hi @JunjieZhu-MSFT, thanks for the reply. Let's continue the discussion in the [Microsoft Learn question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1433378/how-to-enable-hdcp-content-protection-through-uwp?comment=question)